Solving linear diophantine equations - methods and complexity
I'm curious what (if any) are the state-of-the-art methods to find solutions for linear diophantine* equations of N variables, like:
$$
\sum _{i=1} ^{n} a_{i}x_i ~=~ b
$$
Note that I mean a single equation, not a system thereof.
Whether methods exist or not, do we know what is the time complexity class of this problem? (I guess it's some type of NP)
Also, does restricting all variables to non-negative numbers affect the methods and complexity?
*I think the term "diophantine" is not very precise, as I've seen cases where both the coefficients and variables must be integer, but also only the variables. I'm not sure if it affects the answers in any way. In this case I do NOT want to limit the scope to integer or rational coefficients.

Three variable diophantine equation $ax + by + cz = d$ is easily reduced into two two-variable diophantine via solving first $by + cz = \gcd(b, c)$ and then $ax + \gcd(b, c)w = d$. I think the same can be generalized into any $n$ number of variables

@EnEm What if the coefficients aren't integer? Can I use GCD generalized to rationals? Still, what if the coefficients aren't rational? :)

Oh I didn't check the note properly. I think the above should carry forward easily to rationals (multiply both sides by lcm of all denominators before starting), but Im not sure on how to solve even $ax + by = d$ for irrational $a, b ,c$

Also I strongly think that only ILP or something stronger can be used when restricting only to non-negative integers.

Find one solution or all solutions?

One solution would be OK.

The term "diophantine" in "diophantine equation" is quite precise. A diophantine equation is one expressible with a polynomial with integer coefficients in a finite number of integer variables.  If any of the  $\ a_i\ $ or $\ b\ $ in your equation are not rational then it is not a diophantine equation.

Then how are the other equations in integers (Z or N) called? Can we speak of Diophantine solutions?

How do you provide the coefficients? Are they algebraic? If they are real in general then a lot of possible equations will have no solution because for any collection of $a_i$'s the left-hand side can only take a countable number of values while b can take an uncountable amount.

Coefficients can be any real numbers, also transcendental. Yes, some equations may have no solution at all. If it's possible to determine existence of a solution, that's great too.

A polynomial with more than one variable is called Indeterminate Algebra in older Textbooks. In particular polynomial equation of two variables with rational coefficients was studied by Diophantus. Diophantus was not a first who studied these kind of Equations before him Indian Mathematicians - Brahmhagupta & Bhaskara, others sucessfully solved upto 2nd degree & they tried  to solve 3rd & 4th degree. Fermat, Euler - Lagranges solved 3rd - 4th degree today we are doing mistake by calling every equation of these kind is called Diophantine equation

For solving linear Diophantine equations with $n$ variables,
$_1_1+_2_2+…+_i_i=$ where $_i$ and $b$ are integers, and we seek integer solutions $_$.  By using the Matrix Method we can simplify and solve it. This is typically done by transforming the system into a form that is easier to solve, such as the Hermite Normal Form (HNF) or Smith Normal Form (SNF).
Given a system of linear Diophantine equations represented in matrix form:
$A_x=b$
where $A$ is an $m×n$ integer matrix, $x$ is an n-dimensional column vector of variables, and b is an m-dimensional column vector of integers, the goal is to find integer solutions for $x$.
Using HNF:

Transform A into HNF:
Convert the matrix $A$ into its Hermite Normal Form $H$ using integer row and column operations. The HNF $H$ is an upper triangular matrix where each row's leading coefficient (pivot) is positive and to the right of the leading coefficient in the previous row.

Solve the simplified system:
Once $A$ is in HNF, the system $Hx=b'$  (where b' is the transformed b corresponding to the transformations applied to A) is easier to solve. The solution involves back-substitution, starting from the last row.


Using SNF:

Transform A into SNF:
Convert the matrix $A$ into its Smith Normal Form $S$. This involves finding integer matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $PAQ=S$, where $S$ is a diagonal matrix. The entries on the diagonal of $S$ are called the invariant factors of $A$.

Analyze the simplified system:
The original system $Ax=b$ is now transformed into $Sy=Pb$ where $x=Qy$. The diagonal form of $S$ makes it straightforward to find integer solutions $y$, which can then be transformed back to the solutions for $x$ using $x=Qy$.


Example:
Consider the linear Diophantine equation:
$3x+6y+9z=12$
Represent this equation in matrix form:
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 6 & 9\end{bmatrix}
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 \\  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}12
\end{bmatrix}
Now let's ransform the matrix into its HNF or SNF. For simplicity, let’s transform it to HNF.
Row operations to simplify by dividing the entire row by 3:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}
Now the equation is:
$x+2y+3z=4$
Solve the simplified system:
Since we have one equation and three variables, express two variables in terms of the third. Let $z=t$, where $t$ is an integer:
$x+2y+3t=4$
$x=4−2y−3t$
Thus, the solutions are:
$x=4−2y−3t$
$y=y$
$z=t$
where $y$ and $z$ are any integers. This provides the general integer solution to the original equation.

Hi. Please re-read my question and all the comments.
